# how to php convert this time format?

Tags: php, date

i was fetching this date from table in the database like this format

```
Sunday 16th of January 2011 06:55:41 PM
```

and i want to convert it to be like this format

```
11-05-2012
```

how to do that with date function or any function

when i use date function

```
 <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', $v['v_created']); ?></td>
```

i get error message

```
 'Severity: Warning

Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given'
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing a date in that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (just tested on local web server)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set ('Europe/Rome');

$date = "Sunday 16th of January 2011 06:55:41 PM";

//.Strip "of" messing with php strtotime
$date = str_replace('of', '', $date);

$sql_friendly_date = date('y-m-d H:i', strtotime($date));

echo $sql_friendly_date;

?>
```

You can format the date as you prefer changing the first parameter of Date function according to: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Just edited try this one :)

Oh just see the format you requested is "d-m-Y"

Answer (score 1):

You have the following format:

```
 Sunday 16th of January 2011 06:55:41 PM
```

that is a string based format, so the date information is more or less encoded in a human readable format. Luckily in english language. Let's see, that are multiple things all separated by a space:

```
 Sunday   - Weekdayname
 16th     - Date of Month, numeric, st/nd/th form
 of       - The string "of".
 January  - Monthname 
 2011     - Year, 4 digits
 06:55:41 - Hour 2 digits 12 hours; Colon; Minute 2 digits; Colon; Seconds 2 digits
 PM       - AM/PM
```

So you could separate each node by space and then analyze the data. All you need is all  Monthnames and the `sscanf` function because you only need to have the month, date of month and year:

```
$input = 'Sunday 16th of January 2011 06:55:41 PM';
$r = sscanf($input, "%*s %d%*s of %s %d", $day, $monthname, $year);
```

Which will already give you the following variables:

```
$monthname - string(7) "January"
$day       - int(16)
$year      - int(2011)
```

So all left to do is to transpose the monthname to a number which can be done with a map (in the form of an array in PHP) and some formatted output:

```
$monthnames = array(
    'January' => 1,
    # ...
);

printf("%02d-%02d-%04d", $day, $monthnames[$monthname], $year);
```

So regardless of which problem, as long as the input is somewhat consistently formatted you can pull it apart, process the gained data and do the output according to your needs. That is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this. always worked for me

```
$date = Sunday 16th of January 2011 06:55:41 PM

$new_date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($date));

echo $new_date;
```

Comment: forgot to mention. u should strip the 'of' word from the date first.

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using `Sunday 16th of January 2011 06:55:41 PM` is a wrong format.from the form you are inserted this date in database should be in date(Y-m-d) than the value of date inserted in database like:-  11-05-2012. and you can fetch this and get the format what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$old_date = date('l, F d y h:i:s');         // returns Saturday, January 30 10 02:06:34

$new_date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($old_date));

echo $new_date
?>




     more details about date plz visit this url

    http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
```