# Correct way to format user DOB's when inserting with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having some strange issues with a simple `$dob` form input and database insert with PDO into a mysql table of datatype `date`.

**Input Form** (example):

```
<select name="dob-month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
</select>
<select name="dob-day">
    <option value="01">1</option>
</select>
<select name="dob-year">
    <option>2013</option>
</select>
```

**PHP** (basic):

```
$data = $_POST; //passed through mvc

$day = trim($data['dob-day']);
$month = trim($data['dob-month']);
$year = trim($data['dob-year']);

$birthdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day));

$stmt = $this->core->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo (birthdate) VALUES (:birthdate)");
$stmt->bindParam(':birthdate', $birthdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

But it's giving dates without the day? so just 2013-12 work correctly but the day is always -01?

Is it to do with the select format of the date?

Comment: what field type is birthdate?

Comment: what does $year, $month and $day are, And maybe you need strtotime() ?

Comment: Try with `strtotime("$day $month $year")` and also take care what locale does with this. Your question reminds me a bit of: [strtotime With Different Languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6988536/367456) and [how to php convert this time format?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11931209/367456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the PHP `date()` command accepts only an official UNIX timestamp to be converted into the specified format. Secondly, while your form has variables named `dob-month`, `dob-day` and `dob-year`, it looks as if you are trying to use them in the variables `$month`, `$day` and `$year` in your PHP processing script.
Why don't you start with a nice PHP `date` tutorial explaining the difference between a **DATE STRING**, a **DATE OBJECT**, and a **UNIX TIMESTAMP**. Read up on PHP's `strtotime()` function, and mySQL's `DATE_FORMAT()` function. By the time you get done with those things, you should be informed enough to return and submit a much moire educated question.

**edits / additional info**

```
<select name="dob-month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="dob-day">
    <option>1</option> // Same here - stick to a single digit
    <option>15</option>
    <option>31</option>
</select>
<select name="dob-year">
    <option>2013</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
$day = intval(trim($data['dob-day']));
$month = intval(trim($data['dob-month']));
$year = intval(trim($data['dob-year']));
$birthdate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
```

Comment: Thanks for the sarcasm, I edited the php due to the post being passed through a controller and didn't want to confuse everyone then forgot to put it back in. I understand the types and even with `$birthdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day));` I'm still getting issues?

Comment: It was hardly sarcasm. It remains a poorly worded question with just BARELY enough supporting code to figure out what;s going on with your script(s). `strtotime()` may not be reliable enough to use in this situation. You may have to go the long way with `mktime()`.

Comment: echo `$birthdate` a few times and see if it's not getting obliterated due to the `strtotime()` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter of

```
  date()
```

is an integer value (a natural number), not a dash separated string. Read the [man-page of date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Quite like you'd like to do something like this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $year."-".$month."-".$day ));
```

**At the other side: This operation constructs a date string passes it along to date() - which in turn returns the same date string ;-)**

Comment: When inserting a date into a `date` should you use the timestamp or string of the date in format `'Y-m-d'`?

Comment: @Silver89 No you pass an integer value as the second parameter to date(). The integer value is a UNIX timestamp. The source of the current time as a UNIX timestamp is time(). Therefore, date('Y-m-d', time()) is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$birthdate = $_POST['dob-year']."/".$_POST['dob-month']."/".$_POST['dob-date'];
```

Instead of this code

```
$birthdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day));
$birthdate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
```